# Will setting default headers on axios headers reflect in all imported instances of axios in other modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Accross my React modules, I'm using Axios for HTTP requests. My question is, if I have two modules (e.g. components) A and B and both import axios, does setting the default header in module A be reflected in module B? or would I have to set it in both modules?

The other part of my question is: does commonjs differ from es6 modules in this area? I know commonjs uses a cached version so you have a singleton and so I assume that changes are reflected in all files? am I wrong?

setting default headers:

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]  = `Bearer sdssdsdssd...`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** Please refer to docs https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults. Especially to line

> You can specify config defaults that will be applied to every request.

You can setup your own instance for axios request. Also in docs https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults.

**Q2:** Probably because you are on UI and using webpack, or any other bundler it does not matter. Because built file will be the same. But of course there are differences in architect. Try this https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b